# Hopfion with only in-plane vortex rather than skyrmion along the torus?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topology, solitons, skyrmion, hopf-algebra

A simple torus-like [hopfion](http://hopfion.com/) with hopf charge $Q_H=1$ will typically exhibit a skyrmion at each slice cutting the toroidal circle. What if the skyrmion is replaced by an in-plane 2D vortex, i.e., we set the vector component $S_3=0$ for all such slice skyrmions? Is it still something nontrivial, e.g., what is $Q_H$ now or any other topological index?